# One big Database from a few Excels - numbering tickets in order

Tags: sql, database, excel, ms-access

Database from a few Excel Woorkbooks - problem with numbering tickets_ID
Hi People,

I'm newbie here - please understand this.

I would like to describe my problem here. 
First of all I have 2 Excel woorkbooks with the same layout tables connected to Access.

In these woorkbooks there are tables with Ticket number like this: Login & _000001, Login & _000002.

[image]

When User is creating new Ticket_ID , automatically User's Ticket is getting number from last row in this table + 1 so for example lastrow is 20 the number of Ticket will be Login_000021. Next copy of this table of each user is moved to Access Table.
From the second user it is the same - the difference is only with Login.

And the last thing - I have Query in Acccess which is joining these 2 tables for one big and thanks to this I have One big Excel workbook which people are using for reporting and implementing changes.

My clients want to have in other way - they want to have number like this (combination of year and number from second column): 
5000020_1_2016, 
5000020_2_2016, 
**5000020_3_2016,** 
5000150_1_2016, 
5000150_2_2016, 
**5000020_4_2016**

And this should be done in order in real time. So User 1 Is trying to create new Ticket in Excel, than whole Database with all numbers from Access is downloaded to table to this Excel woorkbook and on this basis the number is automatically added. 
I wonder how to do this - whether add time column and upload it to Access for each Ticket, next download it and sort in proper way? Or maybe other ideas

Please help me with solving this solution,
Best Regards,
Jacek Antek

Answer (score 0):

See this link for sequential numbering with a year-component:

https://scottgem.wordpress.com/?s=sequential+numbering

You could tailor the example to your needs.